# Is it possible to filter by 2nd cluster key without specifying 1st?

Tags: cassandra, primary-key

I am just starting to get a hand of `cassandra`.

And I am curious if I can do the following:

```
session.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mykeyspace.newtable 

(user_id int,
 item_id int,
 tstamp timestamp,
 PRIMARY KEY(user_id, item_id, tstamp))")
```

My Understanding:

I know that my `user_id` is a partition key, and I can only filter on it by `=`. My `item_id` and `tstamp` are cluster keys. I can filter of `item_id` by range (using equality symbols), and for a given `item_id` I can filter by range for `tstamp`, but if `item_id` is not specified, I cannot filter by `tstamp` at all.

My question:

Is there a way to specify my `PRIMARY KEY` such that I can:

1) filter by `=` for user_id (I already have it)

2) filter by `=` item_id (I already have it)

3) filter by range for tstamp (I don't have it)

If I change my `PRIMARY KEY` specification to:

```
PRIMARY KEY(user_id, tstamp, item_id)
```

Then I would no longer be able to filter by `item_id`. So if there was a way to somehow filter by `item_id` without specifying `tstamp` I would have my answer.

Is there a way to achieve what I am looking for?

Comment: I wish more people would ask this question, instead of just throwing in a secondary index or two, and then coming on later and asking us why things are so slow.  Bravo!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to this is to build two tables. One with each primary key scheme you want. Duplicating data in tables with different schemas is relatively cheap since writes are so fast in Cassandra.